# different types of a binding variable not visible

Tags: angularjs, binding, formatting

I have `{{ds.number | number:2}}`  in my binding expression. I want when the number is a decimal number to show in binding only 2 decimal digits. But in some cases when the number is zero i want to show  "-"  on this place. As soon as I added the filter `|number:2`  the displaying of the "-" stopped working. Please help with suggestions in this situation.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. ds.number can be either a number or a string with "-" value, is that it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this expression. if you are on Angular version 1.1.5 and above i think.

`{{(data===0) ? "-":(data | number:2)}}`

Comment: good catch, didn't thing that `if()?:` will work for filter :)